# Receiving all data sent with C sockets

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

If I write a server, how can I implement the receive function to get all the data sent by a specific client if I don't know how that client sends the data?
I am using a TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: A security hint: If you use a size value, never rely on the size value to be correct. Always program as if it is a lie. Bad guys might send corrupted data to your program and if you assume the size is right it could make your program get stuck (Denial of Service) or crash. If it crashes there's probably a shell-code attack in there somewhere too.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include more details? You are designing a proxy server? Is it okay to replace IP/TCP as long as the rest of the data is left intact? Are you serving multiple clients and passing the data to multiple servers? Are you concerned with receiving all data before passing it off to the server, or can you receive a packet and hand it off immediately?

Comment: Please update your question. As it's currently written it is too vague and unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have no protocol defined, then all you can do is accept groups of bytes from the client as they arrive.  Without a defined protocol, there is no way to know that you have received "all the bytes" that the client sent, since there is always the possibility that a network failure occurred somewhere between the client and your server during transmission, causing the last part of the stream not to arrive at the server.  In that case, you would get the usual end-of-stream indication from the TCP socket (e.g. recv() returning 0, or EWOULDBLOCK if you are using non-blocking sockets), so you would know that you aren't going to receive any more data from the client (because the TCP connection is now disconnected)... but that isn't quite the same thing as knowing you have received all of the data the client meant for you receive.

Depending on your application, that might be good enough.  If not, then you'll have to work out a protocol, and trust that your clients will abide by the rules of that protocol.  Having the client send a header first saying how many bytes it plans to send is a good approach; or having it send some special "Okay, that's all I meant to send" indicator is also possible (although if you do it that way, you have to watch out for false positives if the special indicator could appear by chance inside the data itself)

Answer (score 1):

One call to `send` does not equal one call to `recv`. Either send a header so the receiver know how much data to expect, or send some sort of sentinel value so the the receiver knows when to stop reading.

Comment: But if I cant control the sending part,meaning i only receive from a specific client(not implemented by me) how do I know how the data is sent ?

Comment: @vBx it depends on the protocol in use by this server. TCP is a stream of bytes, it knows nothing about message boundaries.

Comment: @ Sam Miller: well i use TCP, hmmm so if it doesnt know nothing about message boundaries how can I implement a receive function to receive all the data ? :)

Comment: @vBx that is the point of my answer to your question. Maybe you should edit your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve rather than ask how to receive all the data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to design your protocol.

ASCII protocols usually use a special character to delimit the end of the data, while binary protocols usually send the length of the data first as a fixed-size integer (both sides know this size) and then the variable-length data follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine size with your data in one buffer and call send once. People usually use first 2 bytes for size of data in a packet. Like this,

```
|size N (2 bytes) | data (N bytes) |
```

In this case, you can contain 65535 byte-long custom data.

Since TCP does not preserve message boundary, it doesn't matter how many times you call send. You have to call receive until you get `N size(2 bytes)` then you can keep calling receive until you have `N bytes data` you sent.

UPDATE: This is just a sample to show how to check message boundary in TCP. Security/Encryption is a whole different story and it deserves a new thread. That said, do not simply copy this design. :)

Comment: and if i don't know how a client sends data,if i write only the server part, how do i receive then ?

Comment: @vBx, you can't build server without knowing how client sends packets. This is a 'protocol' you should design for all network communication.

Comment: well i just want to get all the bytes and thats it i don't what to do anything with them,to make it clearer i am making a proxy so that data has to come to the proxy and then i send it to server,so i don't need to process thoose bytes,so i guess,i dont need how that clients send packets...or ?

Comment: @vBx then, why don't you just send whatever you receive until the client closes the connection? If you want to know the end of packet other than "connection close", it means you have to design your own protocol between client and server.

Comment: sorry,but how do i know when the client closes connection ?

Comment: check recv()'s return value. "If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @vBx np. :) but please try to read some basic network programming articles / tutorials first before you start build the proxy server. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

TCP is stream-based, so there is no concept of a "complete message": it's given by a higher-level protocol (e.g. HTTP) or you'd have to invent it yourself. If you were free to use UDP (datagram-based), then there would be no need to do send() multiple times, or receive().
A newer [SCTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) also supports the concept of a message natively.

With TCP, to implement messages, you have to tell the receiver the size of the message. It can be the first few bytes (commonly 2, since that allows messages up to 64K -- but you have to be careful of byte order if you may be communicating between different systems), or it can be something more complicated. HTTP, for example, has a [whole set of rules](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) by which the receiver determines the length of the message. One of them is the `Content-Length` HTTP header, which contains a string representing the number of bytes in the body of the message. Header-only HTTP messages are simply delimited by a blank line. As you can see, there are no easy (or standard) answers.

Comment: the OP's question states TCP is the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream based protocol. As such there is no concept of length of data built into TCP in the same way as there is no concept of data length for keyboard input.

It is therefore up to the higher level protocol to specify the end of the message. This can be done by including the packet length in the protocol or specifying a special end-of-message byte sequence.

For example HTTP headers are terminated by a double `\r\n` sequence and the length of the message body can be obtains from the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: `Content-Length` is still an optional header, and if it's not provided, you can not really know, other than relying on `recv` returning `0` to indicate a connection close.